# Eclipse Sequoyah Cannot debug native JNI code: No connection machine actively refused it

Tags: c++, eclipse, debugging, java-native-interface, android-ndk

I'm following steps in this document: 
http://www.eclipse.org/sequoyah/documentation/native_debug.php

Same as this guys issue:  http://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/m/724431/

I just changed the gdb.setup file to point to port  5039 as indicated and this is what happens.

Why would there be both nu debugging symbols found, AND no connection could be made?

Here is the log in eclipse:

```
D:\ws\test\Project\obj\local\armeabi\gdb2.setup:1: Error in sourced command file:
Undefined command: "1set".  Try "help".
(no debugging symbols found)
31-gdb-set confirm off
31^done
32-gdb-set width 0
(gdb) 
32^done
33-gdb-set height 0
(gdb) 
33^done
34-interpreter-exec console echo
(gdb) 
34^done
35-gdb-show prompt
(gdb) 
35^done,value="(gdb) "
36-gdb-set auto-solib-add on
(gdb) 
36^done
37-gdb-set stop-on-solib-events 0
(gdb) 
37^done
38-gdb-set stop-on-solib-events 1
(gdb) 
38^done
39-target-select remote localhost:5039
(gdb) 
&"localhost:5039: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.\n"
localhost:5039: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.
39^error,msg="localhost:5039: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it."
(gdb) 
40-gdb-exit
40^exit
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried the tutorial you are referring to, and didn't succeed. Then I used these tutorials and got debugging working like charm:

http://mhandroid.wordpress.com/2011/01/23/using-eclipse-for-android-cc-development/

http://mhandroid.wordpress.com/2011/01/23/using-eclipse-for-android-cc-debugging/#more-23

Comment: Glad it these worked for you.  I however stuck on trying to run the C++ debug configuration. It says that my Android Project is not a C++ project.  Please see my posting here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8409693/android-jni-debug-eclipse-project-specified-in-the-launch-configuration-is-no

Comment: Options I see in Helios is the convert Android/Java to C++ and not just add C++ nature. On the other hand guide does not indicate either is needed.  How did you get this to work.  Thanks.

Comment: Well I tried again and still no luck. Really the second post is almost the same as Sequayah what is the difference?

Comment: @Androider: Why use Helios? The current release is Indigo.