# Android JNI Debug: Eclipse : Project specified in the launch configuration is not a C/C++ one

Tags: android, eclipse, debugging, java-native-interface, android-ndk

I'm on Eclipse Indigo.  I'm trying to Debug the JNI/C++ portion of an Android Eclipse Project.  I don't want to convert my Android project over to a C++ project for obvious reasons.  I don't mind adding C++ nature but the options I have tried so far change my project to a C++ project that needs a make file.  So the debug proceedures is that I start a Java Android Debug session, startup the ndk-gdb debug server, and then I need to attach the C++ debugger somehow. So I created a C++ Debug Profile in addition to the Android Java Debug Config.  But when I start it up I get Project specified is not C/C++.  Should I create a dummy C++ project just to get the debug session working? Thanks

PS: I am following the steps in this guide to debug JNI in Android:
http://mhandroid.wordpress.com/2011/01/23/using-eclipse-for-android-cc-debugging/#more-23

And it does not indicate the need to create a separate C++ project.

Answer (score 1):

The option "Convert to C/C++ project" is what you need.