# How do I add a C++ Nature to an Eclipse Android Project without converting it to C++ Project

Tags: android, c++, debugging, java-native-interface, android-ndk

I want to add C++ nature only to my Android Project.  The reason is I want to run a C++ debug configuration against the JNI portion of the project. If I convert to project to C++ I don't think my Android Debug project will run anymore so I would just like to add the C++ Nature. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

AFAIK, you can't debug JNI code from Eclipse. Adding the C++ nature won't change this. You need to use gdb. The [Sequoyah](http://www.eclipse.org/sequoyah/) project offers such integration, but I don't know who well it works with current ADT versions. Another, the recently released [DS-5](http://blogs.arm.com/software-enablement/633-arm-ds-5-community-edition-enabling-the-android-developer-community/) should make this easier.

Comment: I am not seeing the option to a C++ Nature. I am seeing only the option to completely convert the project to a C++ project.  But if I do this it is no longer Java/Android so then my Android debug config will not run.  Do you know how to just/only add the C++ nature without the project conversion?

Comment: Sorry for the typo. You _can't_ debug JNI code by adding the C++ nature, so don't. Use one of the tools I linked, or gdb on the command line.

Comment: http://mhandroid.wordpress.com/2011/01/23/using-eclipse-for-android-cc-debugging/#more-23 seems to indicate that its possible to run C++ Debug Configuration after starting up the gdb on command line.

Comment: I tried Sequoyah but I ran into problem connecting: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8395670/eclipse-sequoyah-cannot-debug-native-jni-code-no-connection-machine-actively-re

Comment: http://www.eclipse.org/sequoyah/documentation/native_debug.php also indicates that a C++ Debug Config is created without indicating that a C++ project needs to be created.  I have Sequoyah installed, and its not clear that Sequayah resolves this issue.  Do I need to create a C++ application/project for Sequoyah?

Comment: I see they found some way to glue them together without a dedicated plugin. I haven't tried it, so can't help you there. Follow the blog instructions and check the comments, seems people are getting mixed results.

Comment: I have extrapolated that they must be creating a dummy C++ project but this is really not very clean.  So now its trying to attach however it says:

Comment: (no debugging symbols found) \local\armeabi\gdb2.setup:4: Error in sourced command file:
:5039: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.
localhost:5039: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it

Comment: Android.mk has LOCAL_CFLAGS := -g but still not working.  I'm going to post this one as separate question.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8410639/debugging-android-jni-c-no-debug-symbols-found-target-machine-actively-refused