# Debugging Android JNI/C++ No Debug Symbols Found Target Machine Actively Refused Connection

Tags: android, eclipse, debugging, java-native-interface, android-ndk

Here is the console log:

(no debugging symbols found)
D:\ws\test\MyProject\obj\local\armeabi\gdb2.setup:4: Error in sourced command file:
:5039: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.
localhost:5039: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.

Following debug steps for eclipse plugin sequoyah:
http://www.eclipse.org/sequoyah/documentation/native_debug.php

I'm almost at the end trying to connect the C++ Debugging.

My Android.mk does have the following set:

LOCAL_CFLAGS := -g

this is the gdb I'm using ... I'm on windows.
C:\android-ndk-r7\toolchains\x86-4.4.3\prebuilt\windows\bin\i686-android-linux-gdb.exe

I'm still trying to get this to work for days. Could you provide someone (hopefully on Sequoyah team) provide some insight into how to get this to work on Windows.

Comment: Could someone who has done Android JNI Debugging please respond.  I have been trying to get this setup for days.

Comment: Am I the only one who needs to debug C++ code in an Android Project?

Comment: You really need to be patient. _No one_ is going to give you answers _within minutes_ and _for free_. If you are getting connection refused, this probably means some daemon is not running, check relevant scripts, etc. Also, if you want to reach the Sequoyah team, etc., SO may not be the best place. Check their official mailing lists, etc. and post there.

Comment: The value of an answer diminishes with time.  I think there must be people on this board that have got this working.

Comment: stuck in the same place!

Answer (score 0):

Did you run ndk-gdb from the terminal in the project directory? That fixed the problem for me

Answer (score 0):

You need to do adb forwarding before you can do that.

do adb forward tcp:5039 tcp:5039 and then try

Answer (score 0):

The instructions mention doing this to your gdb2.setup file:

> removing the target remote:5039 statement

Did you remember to do that?